# Getting the length of a string from a the first instance of a particular character

Tags: python

The title sums it up really. I need to find the length of a string in python from the first instance of a particular character. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = 'this is a test string'
>>> len(s[s.index('some_character'):])
```

Where `some_character` is the character that you're searching for.

[`len()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#len)
[Good answer for list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: you forgot a closing parenthesis after the ' on your second line of code

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
a = 'blahblahbalh'
b = a.find('b')
c = len(a[b:])
```

Answer (score 0):

len(myStr[myStr.find('insert character here'):])